# MacOS Catalina Wont connect to MONGODB Server on Google Compute Engine

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine, macos-catalina

I have a problems on my Macbook 15" Catalina to access Mongodb run in docker compute engine. If i use other laptop connection work well without error or with other os like ubuntu or windows that no problems. Cant connect just in my macbook 15" with os Catalina.

Error on mongo command :

```
▶mongo [PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]/admin -u username -p password                

MongoDB shell version v3.6.14
connecting to: mongodb://[PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-11-23T18:22:30.975+0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() Connection reset by peer [PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]
2019-11-23T18:22:30.975+0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: SocketException socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [[PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]] 
2019-11-23T18:22:30.975+0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '[PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

show error if i use --ssl flag :

```
▶mongo [PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]/admin -u username -p password --ssl --verbose

MongoDB shell version v3.6.14
connecting to: mongodb://[PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-11-23T11:47:19.836+0700 D NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:[PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]
2019-11-23T11:47:19.839+0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() Connection reset by peer [PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo]
2019-11-23T11:47:19.839+0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: socket exception [RECV_ERROR] for [PublicIP-VMInstance]:[PortMongo] :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:263:13
@(connect):1:6
2019-11-23T11:47:19.839+0700 D -        [thread1] User Assertion: 12513:connect failed src/mongo/shell/shell_utils.cpp 279
2019-11-23T11:47:19.839+0700 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 3447601 limit: 0
2019-11-23T11:47:19.840+0700 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 1641 limit: 0
2019-11-23T11:47:19.840+0700 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 3937 limit: 0
2019-11-23T11:47:19.841+0700 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 9 limit: 0
2019-11-23T11:47:19.841+0700 D -        [main] User Assertion: 12513:connect failed src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/proxyscope.cpp 302
exception: connect failed
```

If use GUI Client like NoSQLBooster show error :

```
12:53:53.307  *** Starting MongoClient.connect ***
{"options":{"appname":"NoSQLBoosterV5.2.7_125336.468","autoReconnect":true,"keepAlive":60000,"poolSize":0,"promoteLongs":false,"promoteValues":false,"reconnectTries":172800,"socketTimeoutMS":0,"sslValidate":false,"useNewUrlParser":true},"uri":"mongodb://username:******@IPPublic-VMInstance:PORTMONGO?authSource=admin"} 

12:53:53.311  *** Connect Error ***
{"errorLabels":["TransientTransactionError"],"message":"failed to connect to server [IPPublic-VMInstance:PORTMONGO] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET]","name":"MongoNetworkError","stack":"MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [IPPublic-VMInstance:PORTMONGO] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET]\n    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Applications/NoSQLBooster for MongoDB.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)\n    at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at connect (/Applications/NoSQLBooster for MongoDB.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)\n    at callback (/Applications/NoSQLBooster for MongoDB.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:109:5)\n    at runCommand (/Applications/NoSQLBooster for MongoDB.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:129:7)\n    at Connection.errorHandler (/Applications/NoSQLBooster for MongoDB.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:321:5)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)\n    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/NoSQLBooster for MongoDB.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:321:10)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)\n    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"}
```

I have try with this tutorial :

1. openssl problems 
   https://community.exploratory.io/t/mongodb-ssl-connection-error-on-mac-os-x/832  [ still not working ]
2. use --ssl but in other laptop work well without this options

Comment: Is port exposed [ to which you are trying to establish connection ] to external world from computer machine ?

Comment: Yes, port open. I use my windows to connect this mongodb work well. But just in my mac show that error. I also try with another macOs - work well.

Comment: Window and other macOs you refereed, were on same network as yours ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Ip mongodb ping from my Mac is connected

Comment: Can you please try these steps: 

   1: Go to your mongoDB Atlas Dashboard
   2: Open Network Access (its there in side navbar)
   3: Click on ADD IP ADDRESS
   4: Click on allow from Any IP Address ( it basically give access to your dynamic IP address)

Comment: i dont use Mongodb Atlas. I think the problems on my macbook. How to check network on my mac not blocked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple has made TLS requirements stricter in Catalina. I have a similar case where the connection from Catalina fails using the mongo cli client. I couldn't find statements about changes in behavior of SSL specifically (which I am using). They may have changed something they didn't communicate.

About Catalina TLS changes: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176

If I run a VM Ubuntu on Catalina, I'm able to connect from there. Also macs with Mojave can connect just fine using the same certificates, keys, and network.

Below is the error I'm seeing. It's slightly different to yours but also something that only happens on Catalina.

```
mongo --host myhost.com --ssl --sslCAFile ca.pem --sslPEMKeyFile client.pem -u myuser -p
W  CONTROL  [main] Option: ssl is deprecated. Please use tls instead.
W  CONTROL  [main] Option: sslPEMKeyFile is deprecated. Please use tlsCertificateKeyFile instead.
W  CONTROL  [main] Option: sslCAFile is deprecated. Please use tlsCAFile instead.
MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://myhost.com:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
E  NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: Host name mismatch; connection rejected
E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server myhost.com:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed:
SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: Host name mismatch; connection rejected :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I suggest you try generating new certificates that match Apple's new requirements if that's at all possible. Another thing you could try would be to run a Linux VM on your Mac and see if the connection works from there. If it does, I reckon it would narrow the issue down to the certificates themselves.

Update: Docker seems to be an alternative for the VM. Using a Docker container on a Mac with Catalina I can connect to mongo just fine.

Comment: How we generate new certificates in mac ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on certificates but this Google documentation looks relevant: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates

Answer (score -1):

Are you **certain** that `PublicIP-VMInstance` and `PortMongo` are resolving to IP addresses and a port by your mongo client? I'm running MacOS X 10.15.1 (Catalina) and Mongo client 4.2.1 and connections work perfectly for me using a connection string like this:

`/opt/local/bin/mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --host=mongo.mydomain.com:27017 -u mongoMatt -p dont*You*Wish`

Comment: FWIW, that's the same type of connection string (I have it saved as a shell alias) I've been using for MongoDB since the early 3.x days.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer, but still not working with error log : 
connecting to: mongodb://[IPPUBLIC]:[PORT]/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-12-04T09:07:03.380+0700 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server [IPPUBLIC]:[PORT], connection attempt failed: HostUnreachable: Connection reset by peer :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-12-04T09:07:03.382+0700 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-12-04T09:07:03.382+0700 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1